# As publicaçoes estao ficando na ultima pagina no sistema de paginaçao PHP MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Boa noite. Alguém me ajuda em um problema que estou tendo?
Bom... fiz um sistema de postagens com paginação, mas quando eu adiciono mais dados no banco os novos dados ficam na ultima pagina ao invés de ficar na primeira, alguém sabe como reverter isso?

```html
<?php if (!isset($_GET['busca'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
  }
 

  $busca = mysqli_real_escape_string($conecta, $_GET['busca']);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM postagem WHERE titulo LIKE '%".$busca."%' OR original LIKE '%".$busca."%' LIMIT $inicio, $total";
  $todos = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT * FROM postagem WHERE titulo LIKE '%".$busca."%' OR original LIKE '%".$busca."%'");

  $tr = mysqli_num_rows($todos);
  $tp = $tr / $total;


$query = mysqli_query($conecta, $sql);
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $titulo = $resultado['titulo'];
  $episodio = $resultado['episodio'];
  $tituloo = $resultado['original'];
  $img = $resultado['img'];
  $id = $resultado['id'];
  
  echo "<div class='bg-cont'><a href='post.php?conteudo=$id'><img src='$img' />$titulo<p><span>$episodio</span></a></div>";

}
     echo "<div class='limpar'></div>";
     echo "<div class='paginas'>";
$anterior = $pc -1;
    $proximo = $pc +1;
    if ($pc>1) {
      echo "<a href='?busca=$busca&pg=$anterior'><- Anterior</a>";
    }
    echo "|";
    if ($pc<$tp) {
      echo "<a href='?busca=$busca&pg=$proximo'>Próxima -></a>";
    }
echo "</div>";

?>
```

Comment: Tem id Auto-increment? ORDER by id DESC no select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
........$busca."%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $inicio, $total";
```

Se você quiser que as linhas retornem em uma ordem específica, inclua uma cláusula ORDER BY que indique como ordenar os resultados.

ORDER BY 
fornece uma grande flexibilidade para a ordenação dos conjuntos de resultados. Ele tem as seguintes características:

- Você pode mencionar uma ou mais colunas, separadas por vírgulas, para usar na ordenação.
- Por padão, ORDER BY ordena os valores em ordem ascendente (do menor para o maior). Qualquer coluna de ordenação pode ser seguida por ASC se você quiser especificar uma ordem ascendente explicitamente. Essas cláusulas ORDER BY são equivalentes:

  ```
  ORDER BY sobrenome, nome

  ORDER BY sobrenome, nome ASC
  ```

  Para ordenar valores em ordem descendente (do maior para o menor), coloque DESC após o nome da coluna de ordenação.

  ```
  ORDER BY sobrenome, nome DESC
  ```

  Quando você menciona uma coluna seguida por ASC ou DESC , o especificador de direção se aplica a essa coluna. Ele não afeta a direção de ordenação de nenhuma outra coluna listada na cláusula ORDER BY.
- ORDER BY normalmente se refere a colunas da tabela pelo nome:

  ```
  SELECT sobrenome, nome FROM t ORDER BY sobrenome, nome
  ```

  Entretanto, é possível se referir a colunas de outras maneiras. Se uma coluna tiver um aliás, você pode se referir a ele atraves dela.

  ```
  SELECT sobrenome AS ultimo, nome AS primeiro FROM t ORDER BY ultimo, primeiro
  ```

  Você também pode especificar um número correspondente à posição da coluna na lista  de colunas a serem exibidas (1 para a primeira, 2 para a segunda e assim por diante):

  SELECT sobrenome, nome FROM t ORDER BY 1,2

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado